# Can't get user session info from Apache Shiro with Jersey RESFUL API

Tags: java, apache, jersey, jax-rs, shiro

I built a web service application with Jersey Jax-RS web service api, and i added apache shiro security framework in it, I can login to system without problem with apache shiro framework but I want to get current user info from another page and I wrote a GET method for this purpose, but in the GET method I can't get session information from Apache Shiro it returns null, I present code information below, please help me to get session information in GET method.

This is login method and it works fine:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public SonucModel loginDeneme(LoginModel loginmodel) throws ClassNotFoundException {

    shiroUser.setUsername(loginmodel.getUsername());
    shiroUser.setPassword(loginmodel.getPassword());

    //sonuc=logindao.sonucDonder(username, password);

    UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(shiroUser.getUsername(), shiroUser.getPassword());
    subject.login(token);

    // UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password);
    String userName = token.getUsername();
    System.out.println("userName:" + userName);

    if(subject.hasRole("admin")) {
        Session session = subject.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute(CURRENT_USER_KEY, "admin");

        sonucmodel.setSonuc("admin");
        return sonucmodel;
    }
    else if(subject.hasRole("kasiyer")) {

        Session session = subject.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute(CURRENT_USER_KEY, "kasiyer");
        /* String username = (String) session.getAttribute(CURRENT_USER_KEY);
        System.out.println("Session: " + username);*/
        sonucmodel.setSonuc("kasiyer");
            Session session1 = subject.getSession(false);
            if(session1!=null) {
                String username = (String) session.getAttribute(CURRENT_USER_KEY);
                System.out.println("Session: " + username);
            }
            else if(session1 == null) {
                System.out.println("session boş");
            }

        return sonucmodel;
    }
    //System.out.println("Session: " + username);
    return sonucmodel;

}
```

but, this GET method could not get the session information

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getUser() {

    //Subject subject= SecurityUtils.getSubject();
    Session session = subject.getSession(false);
    String message;
    if(session != null) {
        message = "Current user: " + session.getAttribute(CURRENT_USER_KEY);
    } else {
        message = "No current user, no session created";
    }

    System.out.println(message);

    return message;
 }
```

and this is the shiro.ini file :

```
[main]
jdbcRealm=org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password FROM users where username = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = select role from users where username=?

ds = com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
ds.serverName = localhost
ds.user = root
ds.password = asd123123
ds.databaseName = marketdb
jdbcRealm.dataSource= $ds

authc.loginUrl = /giris.html
#authc.successUrl = /kasiyer/index.html
user.loginUrl = /giris.html


[urls]
/giris.html = authc
/logout = logout
/admin/** = user, roles[admin]
/kasiyer/** = user, roles[kasiyer]
```

Comment: In your `public String getUser()`, `SecurityUtils.getSubject()` is commented out. How do you get/initialise your `subject` variable then?

Comment: I defined it as public in its class